# How do I create an array of individual objects Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, arr

they all point to the same object "bestGamer" I don't want them to do that, I want that each cell in the array will be an individual object with different values in their props.

I want to do it static cause later I want to pass an array, I don't to push in runtime different values

```
const bestGamer = {
        "name" : "",
        "points" : 0    
}
arr2 = new Array(2).fill(bestGamer)
console.log("First:",arr2[0])
console.log("Second:",arr2[1]);    
arr2[0].name ="Yossi"
arr2[0].points++
arr2[1].name ="Dima"
arr2[1].points++
console.log("First:",arr2[0]);
console.log("Second:",arr2[1]);
console.log("Orignal Object",bestGamer);
```

[image]

Comment: please post the raw code instead of image

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That likely won't work, either, because it evaluates the object literal before calling fill, so it'll just fill the array with the same object reference in all indices.

Comment: good point, that's true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a copy while placing it into newArray, `fill(bestGamer)` places same `bestGamer` on all indices so you end up having same reference at all indices

```js
let bestGamer = { a: 1,  b: 2 }
let newArr = new Array(2).fill(0).map(v=> ({...bestGamer}))

newArr[0].a = 10
console.log(newArr)
```

---

Instead of new Array you can use Array.from

```js
let bestGamer = { a: 1,  b: 2 }
let newArr = Array.from({length:2}, () => ({...bestGamer}) )

newArr[0].a = 10
console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: @EddieKnaz `...` is [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: @EddieKnaz See [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/4642212) and the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators).

Comment: alright so using the spread syntax on an object  {...bestGamer} does a clone.
and than I map it to each cell using the map synax, thank you very much guys

Comment: I also could write, seems to work 

arr2 = new Array(2).fill(0).map(v=> ({
  "name" : "",
  "points" : 0    
}))

Answer (score 0):

You're filling the array with `bestGamer`, so it'll be filled with references to that same object. You need to create a new object for each element. An easy way to do this is combining `Array.map` with `Object.assign`:

```
arr2 = new Array(2).fill(0).map(() => Object.assign({}, bestGamer));
```

Comment: You don’t need the `0`. Alternatively: `Array.from({length: 2}, () => ({ ...bestGamer }))`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing parenthesis; I edited it in. While you don't need the 0, I always prefer to give it some value instead of filling with undefined, as a good practice habit when using `fill`.

Comment: _“I always prefer to give it some value instead of filling with undefined”_ — but the `0` doesn’t mean anything; it’s never used, it is immediately discarded, it doesn’t need to be a number. I’d prefer `.fill()`, or more explicitly `.fill(undefined)`, if `fill` is to be used. But, honestly, this looks like a misuse of `fill` anyway, which is why I’d use the `Array.from` approach instead.

Comment: I understand that in this instance it's not used, but in other cases of using `fill` there may not be an immediate map, so I just prefer to be in the habit of always including a non-undefined value. It's all preference. (As for fill vs Array.from, that's also just preference; both do the same thing in basically the same efficiency.)

Answer (score 0):

to create an array that has individual objects, you can do this.

Step 1: declare an array

```
var myArray = [];
```

Step 2: add an object to it

```
myArray.push[{0, 1, 2, 3}]
```

Now your array has 1 item. This item is item[0]. Item[0] is an object. It has multiple values inside of it, in this case 4. so to access the second item inside of item[0] you can have item[0][1].